# Backup MMS on Android without Google Play Services

Tags: backup, sms, restore, mms

Is there a way to backup and restore MMS without Google Play Services? I'm running Graphene OS on a Pixel 3 (no root). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe using one of the [SMS/MMS Backup & Restore apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/file_backup#group_133)? I've never tried them (myself, I use TitaniumBackup, but that requires root). Note 2 of the apps in the list are available via F-Droid; but Epistolaire cannot restore (it just backs up to JSON), and SMS Gate backs up to IMAP (I found no word on restore), so you're probably left with side-loading one of the tracker ridden candidates…